# Dynamic Pivot Add Total With Cube in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot, cube

I am working on a homework about T-SQL. The homework is about showing all goals scored for a team for each week. I managed to do that but the problem is, at the end, they want a row called total which shows all goals scored by each team for the whole season. I tried using CUBE but it didn't work out. My code is:

```
 DECLARE @Weeks VARCHAR(MAX) = ' '
SELECT @Weeks += (QUOTENAME([Week]) + ',')
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT [WEEK] from Fixture
) as a
SET @Weeks = LEFT(@Weeks, LEN(@Weeks) - 1)

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @SQL = '

    select *
    from
    (
    Select Home as Team, [Week] as Weeks, [Home Score] as Goals From Fixture
    group by Home,Week, [Home Score]
    UNION
    Select Away as Team, [Week] as Weeks, [Away Score] as Goals From Fixture
    group by Away, Week, [Away Score]
    ) as A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Goals)
For Weeks
    IN(' + @Weeks + ')
    )b'
exec (@SQL)
```

I have a data table which is named fixture and the columns are like this:
Week, Home, Away, Home Score, Away Score.

This table works for goals each week but when it comes to the row total, I couldn't figure out how to do it. My teacher said that you can use GROUP BY .... with CUBE but I couldn't figure out how to do it. Btw the @Weeks print the following:
 [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34]

Comment: Also the Home and Away are nvarchar's which contain team names

Comment: sample data and desired output would help in trying